# Setting up servlet to add a new customer

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

What I am trying to accomplish is trying to make a new customer in the my servlet when the user clicks submit on a form.  The form is in the form of a jsp file.  So when the user clicks submit it will go to the doPost method in the servlet.  I want to add one to the customer id when I click submit also.  No database is involved yet.  Still learning concepts.

Errors are thrown everytime I click submit.  Both the errors I have in the doPost are thrown.

How can I fix this

### **Servlet**

```
package edu.witc.Assignment03.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Phone;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.States;


@WebServlet(description = "servlet to get act as controller between form and models", urlPatterns = { "/customerServlet","/addCustomer","/addPet", "/customerManagement" })
public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomerServlet() {
        super();
    }

    private List<edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        States state = new States();
        Collection<Phone> phones = phone.getPhoneCollection();
        Collection<States> states = state.getStateCollection();
            session.setAttribute("phones", phones);
            session.setAttribute("states", states);
    }

    private void addCustomer(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to form
            throws IOException, ServletException {
            String url = "/customerManagement.jsp";
            processRequest(request, response);
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("customer", customer);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
     }


    private void addPet(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to pet page
         throws IOException, ServletException {
         String url = "/pets.jsp";
         request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }

    private Customer getCustomer(int customerId) {
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            if (customer.getCustomerId() == customerId) {
                return customer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void makeCustomerReceipt(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

            String url = "/receipt.jsp";
            request.setAttribute("customers", customers);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                String action = request.getParameter("action");
                if("addCustomer".equals(action)) { 
                    System.out.println("doGet add customer");
                    addCustomer(response, request);
                }
                else if("addPet".equals(action)) { 
                    System.out.println("doGet pet");
                    addPet(response, request);
                }
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // update customer
        int customerId = 0;
        Customer testCustomer = new Customer();
        testCustomer.setCustomerId(1);
        testCustomer.setFirstName("Test");
        customers.add(testCustomer);

        try {
            customerId = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           response.getWriter().write("Error: Customer ID could not be parsed to a number");
        }
        Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
        if (customer != null) {
            customer.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            customer.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            customer.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            customer.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
            customer.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
            customer.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
            customer.setZip(request.getParameter("zip"));
            makeCustomerReceipt(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
           response.getWriter().write("Error: customer is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes sense that you get the 2nd error if you've got the first. Since you cannot parse the id, then `customerId` will have value 0 and the test customer you've added by hardcoding has id 1. It's helpful in these circumstances to include the id you was not able to parse in the error message. If you need further help on this, you need to provide more information. E.g. the jsp file, output of all request parameters, etc.

Comment: what would you like the form I was talking about?